# How to Filter Data By Checkbox Using Livewire Laravel

Tags: laravel, checkbox, laravel-livewire

I want to make a filter by checking, in this case, I have one Course table and in this table I include Level Field, where the customer can filter the course by level, for example I have levels like Beginner, Intermediate, and soon. So, my problem is I want to display Level start form ALL, BEGINNER, INTERMEDIATE and soon, so how I can make when they click ALL then all data display than when they checked Beginner and Intermediate then the data where has Beginner and Intermediate value display all not one of them. anyone, please help me, I don't have any idea about this. so far this my code come from `Livewire/SearchCourse`:

```php
public $all,$beginner,$intermediate;

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.search-course', [
        'courses' => Course::when($this->beginner, function ($query, $term){
            return $query->where('level', 'LIKE', "%$term%");
        })
            ->paginate(10)
    ]);
}
```

And this is my code on blade for checkbox:

```html
<div class="card-body border-top">
    <span class="dropdown-header px-0 mb-2">{{ __('Skill Level') }}</span>
    <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input level-checked" wire:model="all"
               id="level" name="level" value="">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="all">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input level-checked" wire:model="beginner"
               id="level" name="level" value="beginner">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="beginner">Beginner</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input level-checked" wire:model="intermediate"
               id="level" name="level" value="intermediate">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="intermediate">Intemediate</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank u so much for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather suggest that you push all the checkboxes into an array, this will make filtering much more simple.

```php
public $courseLevels = [""]; // Default is empty, so "All" is checked

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.search-course', [
        'courses' => Course::when(count(array_filter($this->courseLevels)), function ($query) {
            return $query->whereIn('level', $this->courseLevels);
        })
        ->paginate(10)
    ]);
}
```

Then set the `wire:model` of all your checkboxes to `wire:model="courseLevels"`,

```html
<div class="card-body border-top">
    <span class="dropdown-header px-0 mb-2">{{ __('Skill Level') }}</span>
    <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input level-checked" wire:model="courseLevels" value="" id="all">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="all">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input level-checked" wire:model="courseLevels" value="beginner" id="beginner">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="beginner">Beginner</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input level-checked" wire:model="courseLevels" value="intermediate" id="intermediate">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="intermediate">Intemediate</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will mean that if you have no checked checkboxes at all, or if the only value is empty (your "All" value), then the first argument to `when()` is false, because `count(array_filter($this->courseLevels))` will only count values that are non-empty - and everything will be returned. When there are values, the first argument to `when()` is true, and you will add the filter to limit the course-levels. I'm assuming that the levels are actually `intermediate` and `beginner`, so that we don't need the `LIKE` operator, and can use `whereIn()` instead.

Comment: Thank u so much for your suggest bro. I'll try with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to the following with [Lifecycle Hooks](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks)

```
public $courses = [];

public $filters = [
    'all' => false,
    'beginner' => false,
    'intermediate' => false,
];

public function updatedFilters()
{

    $result = new Collection();

    if ($this->filters['all']) {

        $result = $result->merge(Course::where('level', 'LIKE', "%all%"));

    } elseif($this->filters['beginner']) {

        $result = $result->merge(Course::where('level', 'LIKE', "%beginner%"));

    } elseif($this->filters['intermediate']) {

        $result = $result->merge(Course::where('level', 'LIKE', "%intermediate%"));
    }

    $this->course = $result->paginate(10);
}
```

And these on your view

```
<div class="card-body border-top">
    <span class="dropdown-header px-0 mb-2">{{ __('Skill Level') }}</span>
    <!-- Checkbox -->
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-check-input level-checked"
            wire:model="filters.all"
            id="level"
            name="level"
        >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="all">All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-check-input level-checked"
            wire:model="filters.beginner"
            id="level"
            name="level"
        >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="beginner">Beginner</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check mb-1">
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-check-input level-checked"
            wire:model="filters.intermediate"
            id="level"
            name="level"
        >
        <label class="form-check-label" for="intermediate">Intermediate</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work, because paginated data cannot be stored in a public property. Also, what's the point of your `merge` methods? You run `elseif` blocks, meaning that you will never hit more than one block. Finally, the `Collection` class does not contain a `paginate` method on it, that's for QueryBuilder class.

Comment: Thank u so much for replayed bro. At least i have got some idea.

Answer (score 0):

If at least you handle some function to uncheck previous filter selected, I suggest change it to use radio-buttons or select element.
In my example, you can do it using a select element to filter the table

```
use WithPagination;

public $filter = "";

public function render()
{
   return view('courses-component', 'courses' => $this->getData());
}

public function getData()
{
   return Course::where('level', 'LIKE', "%" . $this->filter . "%")->paginate(5);
}
```

and in view

```
<div class="card-body border-top">
   <select class="form-control" wire:model="filter">
     <option value="">All</option>
     <option value="beginner">Beginner</option>
     <option value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Yap bro, i think like you too, 'cause if i use Radio or Select i can only select one and can't select double. thank u for your suggestion bro.